# Skolem sequence generator algorithm

Tags: algorithm, function

My teacher wants me to write a function that get a integer value N and return array that his length is 2n and contains a skolem sequence for the value.

For example: function(4) will return {4,2,3,2,4,3,1,1}

I don't have idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Skolem sequence for a number *n* is a sequence of integers of size 2×*n* that meets two criteria:

1. for every non-negative number *k* < *n*, there exist exactly two elements *s*<sub>*i*</sub>, and *s*<sub>*j*</sub> in the sequence such that *s*<sub>*i*</sub> = *s*<sub>*j*</sub> = *k*
2. if *s*<sub>*i*</sub> = *s*<sub>*j*</sub> = *k* and *i* < *j* then *j*−*i* = *k*

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SkolemSequence.html

Basically, this means that you need to create a sequence with numbers from 1 to n where each number appears twice. To turn the sequence into a skolem sequence, the two 1's have to be next to each other, the two 2's have to have one number between them, the 3's have to have 2 numbers between them and so on.

This algorithm is more difficult than one would think to create. The easiest way to do this is to check every permutation of your sequence, and  return the first one that works. This is (2n)! complexity, which is horribly slow. Here is one reference for an algorithm which doesn't have n! complexity: 
http://www.cs.mun.ca/~dchurchill/pdf/honours.pdf

I have written the naive algorithm in C++. This will generate Skolem sequences for any given input. This algorithm is horribly slow, but I hope you get the point:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
void start(int num, std::vector<int>& v) { //creates the |2n| sequence
        for(int i = 1; i<=num; i++) {
                v.push_back(i);
                v.push_back(i);
        }
}
bool check(std::vector<int>& v) { //checks to see if sequence is a skolem sequence
        for(int i = 1; i<=v.size()/2; i++) {
                auto j = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), i);
                auto k = std::find(j+1, v.end(), i);
                if(k-j != i) {
                        return false;
                }
        }
        return true;
}
void skolem(int num, std::vector<int>& v) { //permutes the vector to find skolem sequences
        start(num, v);
        while(std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end())){
                if(check(v))
                        break;
        }
}
int main()
{
        int num;
        std::cin>>num;
        std::vector<int> v;
        skolem(num, v);
        std::cout<<"found it"<<std::endl;
        print(v);
}
```

This algorithm will only work for small numbers (less than 10). If you need to process larger sequences, I suggest you check out that link above.

Comment: It is actually (2n!)/2^n, which is still a very big number, but much smaller than 2n!. It's really easy to reduce it to n! which should be practical for n=12.

Comment: Thank you. But I already saw that link and I lost him in the second code. I don't understand what Is the new variable that he added to the function and what he doing with him.

Comment: @spaider11 I think the problem here is that this appears to be more of a research problem than a homework problem.